# Run Elasticsearch on AWS EC2 with Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run Elasticsearch with Docker on an AWS EC2 instance, but when it runs, after a few seconds will be stopped, any of you have any experiences what the problem could be?

This is my Elasticsearch config in the `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
 elasticsearch:
  build:
    context: ./elasticsearch
    args:
      - ELK_VERSION=${ELK_VERSION}
  volumes:
    - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  environment:
    - cluster.name=laradock-cluster
    - node.name=laradock-node
    - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
    - discovery.type=single-node
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms7g -Xmx7g"
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
    - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
    - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
    - cluster.initial_master_nodes=laradock-node
  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
    nofile:
      soft: 65536
      hard: 65536
  ports:
    - "${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:9200"
    - "${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST_TRANSPORT_PORT}:9300"
  depends_on:
    - php-fpm
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

And This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.1

RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install --batch discovery-ec2

EXPOSE 9200 9300
```

Also, I did `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=655360` on my AWS EC2 instance

Notice: my AWS EC2 instance is Ubuntu 18.4

Thanks

Comment: which version of Elasticsearch you are using, kindly share the log, show that will able to help

Comment: I mentioned in my question in the `Dockerfile` which is `7.5.1`

Comment: expecting log as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about your `docker-compose.yaml` as you are not referring this in your dockerfile, **But I am able to reproduce the issue**. I launched same ubuntu 18.4 in my AWS account and used your `dockerfile` to launch a ES docker container using below commands:

```
docker build --tag=elasticsearch-custom .
docker run -ti -v /usr/share/elasticsearch/data elasticsearch-custom
```

And my docker container was also stopping just after starting up as shown below:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-95:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
03cde4a19389        elasticsearch-custom   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   33 seconds ago      Exited (78) 6 seconds ago                       mystifying_napier
```

When checked the logs on console, when starting the docker, I found below error:

> ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed [1]: the default discovery settings
>   are unsuitable for production use; at least one of
>   [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers,
>   cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured

Which is very well known error and can be easily resolved just by adding `-e "discovery.type=single-node"` to docker run command. After adding this in docker run command as below:

`docker run -e "discovery.type=single-node" -ti -v /usr/share/elasticsearch/data elasticsearch-custom`

its running fine as shown below:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
191fc3dceb5a        elasticsearch-custom   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   recursing_elgamal
```